# load model from another module

Tags: cakephp, plugins, model, controller

I'm new in CakePHP. Currently I got a problem in my task. 
I had assigned to create a Plugin name UserManagement and Login in app/Plugin/
The Plugin UserManagement already has completed. But now I having a problem in Plugin Login. Actually I need to use User Model from Plugin UserManagement in Plugin Login. However, I don't know how to write a scripts and what steps first I should taken?

I try before, create LoginsController in Controller. But It display an error mentioned that I need to create Model first. Infact that, I actually plan to use Model from UserManagement.

Please assists. Thank you.
Sorry..my English is bad. TT_TT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add

```
 $this->loadModel(PluginName.ModelName);
```

in our controller and then

```
$data = $this->ModelName->find('WhatEver');
```

Hope this will give you some help.

Comment: Hi Anand Ghaywanker, I had try out your recommended script like above, but below error still come out. 
---------------------------------------------------------
Error: The application is trying to load a file from the UserManagement plugin

Error: Make sure your plugin UserManagement is in the Login\Plugin directory and was loaded
---------------------------------------------------------

Please assists...